# TYPO3 10.4.20: Send email with different template files not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have 2 forms on my TYPO3 custom extension. And a total of 3 template files is there.

Please look at my code, can you help me to point out what's wrong with it?

Now I got following error when I click on the submit button:

[image]

```php
// Set user email template
if(!empty($arguments['requestform'])) {
    $setTemplateAdmin = $this->setTemplateAdmin();
    $setTemplateUser = $this->setTemplateUser();
}else{
    $setTemplateFreeTrialAdmin = $this->setTemplateFreeTrialAdmin();
}
exit;




//subject request Admin Template
public function setTemplateAdmin(){
    $this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename(ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('my_extension').
            'Resources/Private/Templates/my_extension/AdminEmail.html');
    $this->view->assignMultiple([
        'mailOutput' => $userData,
        'settings' => $this->settings,
        'baseurl' => $GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['config']['baseURL']
    ]);
    $mailBody = $this->view->render();
    $mailSent = $this->sendEmail($mailBody, $userData['email'], $this->settings, $userData['requestform']);
}

//subject request User template
public function setTemplateUser(){
    $this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename(ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('my_extensionn').
            'Resources/Private/Templates/my_extension/RequestSubUserEmail.html');
    $this->view->assignMultiple([
        'mailOutput' => $userData,
        'settings' => $this->settings,
        'baseurl' => $GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['config']['baseURL']
    ]);
    $mailBodyUser = $this->view->render();
    $mailSent = $this->sendEmailUser($mailBodyUser, $userData['email'], $this->settings, $userData['requestform']);
}

//Trial request user mail
public function setTemplateFreeTrialAdmin(){
    $this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename(ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('my_extension').
    'Resources/Private/Templates/my_extension/UserEmail.html');
    $this->view->assignMultiple([
        'mailOutput' => $userData,
        'settings' => $this->settings,
        'baseurl' => $GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['config']['baseURL']
    ]);
    $mailBody = $this->view->render();
    $mailSent = $this->sendEmail($mailBody, $userData['email'], $this->settings, $userData['requestform']);
}

// Send Email
public function sendEmail($mailBody, $userEmail, $settings, $requestform)
{
    $mail = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage::class);
    if(!empty($requestform)) {
        $mail
            ->from(new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address($settings['adminfromemail'], $settings['adminfromname']))
            ->to(new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address($settings['admintoemail']))
            ->subject($settings['subreqmailsubject'])
            ->html($mailBody)
            ->send();
    } else {
        $mail
            ->from(new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address($settings['adminfromemail'], $settings['adminfromname']))
            ->to(new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address($userEmail))
            ->subject($settings['adminmailsubject'])
            ->html($mailBody)
            ->send();
    }
}

// Send User Email for Subject Request Form
public function sendEmailUser($mailBodyUser, $userEmail, $settings, $requestform)
{
    $mail = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage::class);
    $mail
        ->from(new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address($settings['adminfromemail'], $settings['adminfromname']))
        ->to(new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Address($userEmail))
        ->subject($settings['subrequsermailsubject'])
        ->html($mailBodyUser)
        ->send();
}
```

`$userEmail` is the value email field. I think its value is not getting.

The form is not submitting it shows 500 error.

Comment: These three methods are using an undeclared variable `$userData` for the recipients address: `setTemplateAdmin(), setTemplateUser(), setTemplateFreeTrialAdmin()`.

Comment: Thank you all for your hints, I have passed the variable $userData with the functional now it is working fine. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass with `$userData` the function call

```
if(!empty($arguments['requestform'])) {
            $setTemplateAdmin = $this->setTemplateAdmin($userData);
            $setTemplateUser = $this->setTemplateUser($userData);
        }else{
            $setTemplateFreeTrialAdmin = $this->setTemplateFreeTrialAdmin($userData);
        }
        exit;
```

And also declare the variable at function definition

```
    public function setTemplateAdmin($userData){
//code here
}
```